# Compare 2 elements in single list

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way to compare 2 elements in single list of python. For example if i have `numbers = [1,3,5,7,9]` i want to compare 1 with 3 and so on till the list ends.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you mean adjacent elements? What do you mean by compare- subtract, or compare for greater/less than?

Comment: manipulate. I want to find whether the list is in arithmetic progression or not and if not print the missing number

Comment: see the `pairwise` recipe on the `itertools` page here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i,j in zip(numbers[:-1],numbers[1:]):
    compare(i,j)
```

This compares all adjacent elements, by lining up the list excluding the last element, and the list excluding the first element.

Comment: You can remove the `[:-1]`, `zip` will iterate only till the shortest list is exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> for element in combinations(numbers, 2):
...     print element
...
(1,3)
(1,5)
(1,7)
(1,9)
(3,5)
(3,7)
(3,9)
(5,7)
(5,9)
(7,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
def compare(x, y):
    """
    here you can put your code, using 'x' and 'y' var
    """
    if (x + y) % 2 == 0:
        return x

l = [1,3,5,7,9]
l2 = reduce(compare, l)
print l2
```

I hope help you ;-)